# Derivation of Ladenburg correction (to calculate viscosity of fluid with Stoke's Law)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, viscosity, navier-stokes, velocity

I am creating a lab report investigating the amount of time it takes for a marble ball to sink to the bottom of a cylinder container filled with sugar syrup. I recorded the amount of time it takes for the marble ball to pass two fixed points, and calculated the velocity. I am then required to calculate the viscosity of the fluid with Stokes's Law. I then formulated the equation:

$$ \eta = \frac{2gr^2 (\rho_b- \rho_f) }{9v} $$

where $\rho_b$ is the density of the marble ball and $\rho_f$ is the density of fluid. To find the terminal velocity $v$ with velocity $v'$, I have to use the following formula called the "Ladenburg correction":

$$ v=v'(1+\frac{1+2.4R}{r}) $$

However, I am unable to derive this formula as there are limited sources on the Internet regarding this. Does anyone know how I can derive this?

Comment: This formula is most likely developed empirically.

Comment: LADENBURG, R. 1907. The influence of walls upon the motion of a sphere in a viscous liquid. Ann. Physik. 23:447.

Comment: Hi @JohnRennie , thanks for the help but do you have a link to that research paper? I am unable to find it. Thanks in advance

Comment: @netbeansnewbie Ladenburg's correction was almost certainly an empirical formula derived from doing lots of experiments. I suspect ever since 1907 people have just been using it without worrying about the details. I don't have the original paper and I couldn't find it anywhere on the Internet. In general with fluid mechanics **everything** is complicated and we're reduced to using empirical formulae.